# Negative hexadecimal representation

Tags: python, assembly, hex, integer-overflow, twos-complement

I had a question which was like this:

> ```
>  mov r15, 0x407116EF3867BBCA  
>  sub r15, 0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D
> ```
>
> ***What value is in r15 after this code executes?***
> (Be careful about integer overflow/underflows)

**Solution:** python 3 math string for debugging: `(i64 - i64_2) % (2**64)` and when I solved this question as per this formula I got **0xaa7a977e96aacd2d**.

My doubt is that answer should have been negative but I think it has been converted in 2's complement. But what is the need to convert it into 2's complement if that's the case? So, am I thinking in the right direction or not? If not then please correct me. Also, what's the logic behind this formula (taking modulo by 2^64).

Comment: You got the same answer I got. Python has infinite length integers.  The modulo 2^64 is to truncate the result to the 64-bit register you have.

Comment: @timroberts No, see what I didn't understand was that instruction will be executed as "r15=r15-1" which will be (0x407116EF3867BBCA - 0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D) so we are subtracting a higher value from a lower one so the answer should have been positive? But we are getting a positive one.

Comment: Python `%` is modulo (always positive), not remainder like RDX after an x86 `idiv` instruction.  Anyway, I wouldn't use `%`.  Bitwise AND like `& 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` seems more intuitive for what you're trying to do (bitwise truncation to 64-bit).

Comment: Also, if this is supposed to be x86-64, that won't assemble: only `mov` can use a 64-bit immediate, and `0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D` doesn't fit in / isn't representable as a 32-bit sign-extended immediate.

Comment: @PeterCordes okay so this modulo operation is the only reason why I am getting this positive value instead of a negative one?

Comment: 0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D is a negative number (the high bit is set).  So, really, you're taking a positive minus a negative, but either way it causes an overflow.

Comment: 0xaa7a977e96aacd2d Is a negative number.

Comment: bits are bits, they are only negative or positive or an address or the number of seconds since an epoch, etc if the programmer uses those bits in that way.  they are neither negative nor positive unless the user sees those bits as a signed number.  if seen as unsigned bits then it is not negative obviosly...

Comment: @prl how could you tell by just looking at the number?

Comment: @old_timer, yes but the question is specifically asking about signed numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in assembly, a 64-bit register value can always be represented by 16 hex digits.  There isn't a separate plus/minus bit; **it's best to think of binary operations like add / sub as unsigned<sup>1</sup>**, and only worry about the [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) interpretation of the final result<sup>2</sup>.

---

That means it's slightly inconvenient to use arbitrary precision calculators like Python 3 integers or [`calc` aka `apcalc`](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/index.html) which show you negative results instead of wrapping like C `uint64_t` when a subtraction underflows past `0`.

There are 2 ways to think about fixing the result to be what you want (in the `[0 .. 2**64-1]` range):

- Modulo reduce it back into that range.  **That's what `%` in Python does.**  (Unlike some other languages like C, or the `idiv` instruction in x86-64 asm, Python % gives you the modulus, always positive, not the remainder.  e.g. `-1 % 2` is `1`, but in C for signed int it's `-1`.

  You can even *manually* do that reduction by adding `2**64` to a negative number, to get the 2's complement binary representation.  Because you know that any add or sub result is going to be no less than `2**64` outside that range, so only one addition (or subtraction for a carry-out add) will be ncessary.
- Bitwise truncate it to 64-bit, taking the low 64 bits of Python's internal extended-precision 2's complement representation.  This depends on Python using 2's complement internally, which is probably guaranteed, and certainly works in practice (presumably at least when Python is running on any normal system that itself uses 2's complement.)

**All three give the same correct results.  In an interactive Python 3.9 session:**

```
>>> (0x407116EF3867BBCA - 0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D)
-6162446570153652947
>>> hex (0x407116EF3867BBCA - 0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D)
'-0x55856881695532d3'

>>> hex( (0x407116EF3867BBCA - 0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D) % (2**64) )
'0xaa7a977e96aacd2d'
>>> hex( (0x407116EF3867BBCA - 0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D) + 2**64 )
'0xaa7a977e96aacd2d'

>>> hex( (0x407116EF3867BBCA - 0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D) & (2**64-1) )
'0xaa7a977e96aacd2d'
```

---

Also, **if this is supposed to be x86-64, that `sub` won't assemble**: only `mov` can use a 64-bit immediate, and `0x95F67F70A1BCEE9D` doesn't fit in (isn't representable as) a 32-bit sign-extended immediate.

But if it did, then CF would be set because there's borrow out of the high bit (because 0x4... - 0x9... = 0xa... wrapped past zero: the left-hand operand of the subtraction was unsigned below the right-hand side).

And OF would be set, because in a signed interpretation (where we look at the MSB as having a place-value of `- 2^63` instead of `+ 2^63`), a positive number minus a larger-magnitude negative number produced such a large positive result that it overflowed to negative.  (i.e. positive - negative = negative implies signed overflow, just like positive + positive = negative would)

And SF=1 according to the MSB of the result.

---

**Footnote 1**:
The high half of widening multiply, and division in general, care about the place-value of the MSB; add/sub don't: 2's complement addition is the same binary operation as unsigned, including wrapping around.  That's why x86-64 only has one `sub` instruction, but has `div` and `idiv`, and for one-operand widening multiply has `mul` separate from the usual `imul`.  But the non-widening forms of imul like `imul eax, r9d` are the same for signed or unsigned.

**Footnote 2**:
If the high bit is set, then it's negative if you interpret the bit-pattern as a 2's complement signed integer, instead of unsigned.  See [Wikipedia's article about 2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  If the first hex digit is 8 to F, the high bit is set, so in your case `0x9...` and `0xa...` represent negative numbers, while `0x4...` represents a positive number.

Comment: Now I understand it clearly, thanks a lot man.

Comment: @heartbeat: Cheers.  If that answers your question, you can mark it as "accepted" using the checkbox under the vote arrows.

Comment: Some assemblers (e.g. nasm) may accept the `sub` with a warning and truncate the constant, making it `sub r15,0xffffffffa1bcee9d`.  Conceivably this could be a trick question asking about that case...

Comment: @NateEldredge: Oh right, NASM just warns and truncates instead of erroring there.  Still, without confirmation this is actually even supposed to be x86-64, not some toy 64-bit ISA, I'm going to leave that extra discussion for comments.  The x86-64 specific stuff that is in the answer works decently as examples for other ISAs (although maybe I should mention that some ISAs set carry = !borrow for sub, opposite of x86)